# General bound on growth with $n$ of maximum of $n$ iid random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $\{X_{n}, n\ge 1\}$ are iid and non-negative and assume that $M_{n}$ is the maximum of $X_1,\ldots,X_{n}$. If $E(X_{1}^p)<\infty$, show that $M_{n}/n^{1/p}$ converges to zero with $n$ in probability. [This is problem 6.7.11b of Resnick's A Probability Path. Part (a) asks you to show that 
$$
P[M_{n}>x]\le nP[X_1>x]
$$
which is not hard but doesn't seem to be strong enough.]

Comment: If you can solve the $p=1$ case you can solve them all. Can you solve the $p=1$ case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from union bound we have:
$$
P(M_n\geq \epsilon n^{1/p})\leq nP(X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p}).
$$
Define $Y=X\mathbf{1}(X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p})$. If $X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p}$ then $Y\geq \epsilon n^{1/p}$. Therefore using Markov inequality:
$$
P(X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p})\leq P(Y\geq \epsilon n^{1/p})\leq \frac{E(Y^{p})}{\epsilon^{p}n}=\frac{E(X^{p}\mathbf{1}(X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p}))}{\epsilon^{p}n}.
$$
As $n\to\infty$, the monotone convergence theorem implies that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}E(X^{p}\mathbf{1}(X\geq \epsilon n^{1/p}))=0,
$$
which proves the result.